# Why is the contained object destroyed first?

Tags: perl

In the code snippet below, the object of class `Foo` contains a reference to an object of class `Bar`. I would expect that the `Foo` object is destroyed before the `Bar` object. Unfortunately, this doesn't always happen. Strangely enough, I get different behaviors on differenct systems: on my laptop and desktop, the code always runs correctly, whereas on 2 VPSs that I tried, the destructors are ran in reverse order (most of the time). All four systems run the same version of perl (5.20.2 on x86_64 linux).

Also, this only happens when a sub (called `abcd` below) contains a reference to the `Foo` object. If I remove that, the problem goes away.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo = Foo->new;

sub abcd {
    $foo;
}

####################

package Foo;

sub new {
    bless {bar => Bar->new}, 'Foo';
}

sub DESTROY {
    my ($self) = @_;
    defined $self->{bar} or print "bar is undefined, this should not happen\n";
}

####################

package Bar;

sub new {
    bless {}, 'Bar';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When it comes to *global destruction*, which happens as the program is exiting, [`perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Destructors) is clear

> The order in which objects are destroyed during the global destruction before the program exits is unpredictable.

This is clearly the case without the `sub abcd` in your posted test program. With the sub, the last reference to the object is *inside* the sub so it reaches the global destruction as well. (I also get different behavior in the two cases, but this is meaningless given the above quote.)

Thus in both cases, with or without the sub, the objects are destroyed in an *unpredictable* order.

When an object is destroyed because the last reference to it went out of scope, things are different. To see such behavior we can add `undef $foo;` as the last line, to trigger controlled destruction

```
my $foo = Foo->new;

undef $foo;

END { say "END block." }

sub abcd { $foo; }
```

This results in `Foo` being destroyed first, with and without the sub. It also happens before the `END` block and before the global destruction phase. (Add prints to `DESTROY` in `Foo` and `Bar` to see.)

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that bit about global destruction in `perlobj`. This is annoying though. I guess I have to resort to an explicit finalization method then.

Comment: @safsaf32  Glad it solved it, thank you for the attribution. I'd say that it depends on how your project is organized and classes laid out. You may be able to whip it into shape with a small tweak. Or, have some sort of a catalog of all objects (a class variable keeping track of them?) and have a routine that triggers their destruction in the desire order. It could be in an `END` block, which could make for a clean design altogether.